# Problems with "It might have been better to...perfect vs present tense"

Tags: sentence-meaning, present-perfect, conditional-constructions, present-tense

Which one of these sentences is correct? And if both are, is there a difference in meaning?

> It might have been better to **use** my sister's clothes.
>
> It might have been better to **have used** my sister's clothes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the simple infinitive is probably appropriate:

It might have been better **to use** my sister's clothes.

You would use the present perfect infinitive if you wanted to indicate that you should have done something **before** some reference event:

> It might have been better **to have asked** him before you took his car.